# Repeat a conditional format rule to several columns

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I try to apply the following G sheet `conditional format rule` to several columns without the need to create such conditions manually. Here is the `custom formula: =REGEXMATCH(LOWER($C:$C), "release|prod")` which has been applied to the range `C1:C990` as you can see within the picture

[image: Click here to see the screenshot of the g sheet table]

How caw we apply the same `conditional format rule` to columns `D,E,F,G,...O`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite your custom formula to:

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(C3), "release|prod")
```

and apply it to range **C3:Z**